# Android emulator freezes on Big Sur

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently upgraded my mac to Big sur and ever since all my android emulators freeze after some minutes, sometimes the freeze is permanent, sometimes it comes back after a few seconds, and sometimes it ends in a crash.

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed by **version 30.5.6** of the Android emulator in the stable channel.

Comment: Im using version 30.8.4